# How to create an animation where the point will move along the elliptical line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

There is the code for creating an ellipse, but now I need to create an animation, where point will move along eptical line. Also I need to change the code, because I need input ellipse's radius with input() function and draw the point in the centre of the ellipse maybe using scatter function.

```
import math  # papildus aprēķiniem
import numpy as np  # matricas datu apstrādei
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # grafiku attēlošanai

img = np.ones((200, 800, 3))  # attēls, augstums, platums, kanālu skaits jeb RGB


def DrawEllipse(xc, yc, rx, ry):
    # xc, yc - elipses centra koordinātes
    # rx, ry - lielāka un mazāka pusass
    xk = 0  # sākotnējās x un y koordinātes
    yk = ry

    # -----------1.daļa
    pk = ry ** 2 - rx ** 2 * ry + 1 / 4 * rx ** 2  # risinošā parametra vērtība

    img[xc + xk, yc + yk] = 0  # zīmējam sākotnejās koordinātes 4 kvadrantiem
    img[xc - xk, yc + yk] = 0
    img[xc + xk, yc - yk] = 0
    img[xc - xk, yc - yk] = 0

    while ry ** 2 * xk < rx ** 2 * yk:
        xk += 1  # vai xk=xk+1
        if pk > 0:  # vidējais punkts atrodas ārpus elipses līnijas
            yk -= 1  # vai yk=yk-1
            pk = pk + 2 * ry ** 2 * xk + ry ** 2 - 2 * rx ** 2 * yk
        else:  # vidējais punkts atrodas elipses līnijas iekšā vai uz tās
            pk = pk + 2 * ry ** 2 * xk + ry ** 2
            # zīmējam elipses koordinātes
        img[xc + xk, yc + yk] = 0  # zīmējam sākotnejās koordinātes 4 kvadrantiem
        img[xc - xk, yc + yk] = 0
        img[xc + xk, yc - yk] = 0
        img[xc - xk, yc - yk] = 0
    # --------2.daļa -> izpildam paši

    pk = ry ** 2 * (xk + 1 / 2) ** 2 + rx ** 2 * (yk - 1) ** 2 - (rx ** 2 * ry ** 2)  # otrs moteicošais parametrs

    img[xc + xk, yc + yk] = 0  # zīmējam sākotnejās koordinātes 4 kvadrantiem
    img[xc - xk, yc + yk] = 0
    img[xc + xk, yc - yk] = 0
    img[xc - xk, yc - yk] = 0

    while yk > 0:
        yk -= 1
        if pk > 0:
            pk = pk - 2 * rx ** 2 * yk + rx ** 2
        else:
            xk += 1
            pk = pk - 2 * rx ** 2 * yk + rx ** 2 + 2 * ry ** 2 * xk
        img[xc + xk, yc + yk] = 0  # zīmējam sākotnejās koordinātes 4 kvadrantiem
        img[xc - xk, yc + yk] = 0
        img[xc + xk, yc - yk] = 0
        img[xc - xk, yc - yk] = 0

        # pk=ry**2-rx**2*ry+1/4*rx**2 #risinošā parametra vērtība Formulu/tikai cita
        # while
        # yk -=1

        return

DrawEllipse(100, 50, 50, 25)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=100, facecolor='w')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please use a proper formatting for the code (inside the function `DrawEllipse` - the indents should go till the return). Please use pep8 conventions and comments in a more accessible language. (There is not too much effort shown in presenting the question at this point.) Please show the own effort to animate the point.

Comment: And also, at the very least, please plot the original ellipse in the proper place within the graph. Your static plot is also not at all similar to the end plot that you want. You can check out the guidelines for posting a question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask